# How to mock IDataRecord?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm trying to mock an `IDataRecord` using Moq.

The mock was created as follows:

```
Mock<IDataRecord> mockDataRecord = new Mock<IDataRecord>();
```

The line under test is:

```
DateTime timestamp = dataRecord.GetValueOrDefault<DateTime>("QUEUE_ADD_TS");
```

Have tried:

```
mockDataRecord.Setup(r => r.GetValueOrDefault<DateTime>("QUEUE_ADD_TS")).Returns(now);
```

...but it gives a runtime error:

> Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked
>   object: r => r.GetValueOrDefault("QUEUE_ADD_TS")

Also tried substituting `It.IsAny<String>()` in place of `"QUEUE_ADD_TS"` but it made no difference. This should be easy but I'm scratching my head - grateful for any advice!

Comment: I see no `GetValueOrDefault<T>` method on the `IDataRecord` interface. Isn't it an extension method?

Comment: Pretty sure its just as the error suggests. GetValueOrDefault is an extension method so cant be directly stubbed. Try stubbing the indexer instead, I'm sure examples will be on SO somewhere :)

Comment: Ah you are both right! Turns out `GetValueOrDefault` is an extension method and is `static` so may not be easily mocked. Not sure quite how this works yet but looking into it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do it like this, quick and dirty:

```
Mock<IDataRecord> dataRecord = new Mock<IDataRecord>();
dataRecord.Setup(column => column["applicationno"]).Returns("foobar");
dataRecord.Setup(column => column["numberOfApplications"]).Returns(12);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock static or extension methods since most of the mocking frameworks use dynamic proxies under the hood.

In your test, do not stub the extension method. Instead, stub the original method itself, like:

```
mockDataRecord.Setup(r => r.GetValue<DateTime>("QUEUE_ADD_TS")).Returns(now);
```

You should test the extension method separately, like:

1. Stub the GetValue method and asserting that GetValueOrDefault returns the stubbed value.
2. Donot stub GetValue method, and assert that GetValueOrDefault returns the default value.

Comment: This is indeed what I'm now doing - hadn't actually come across extension methods before! (I dunno, you go away from c# for a few years come back and the goalposts have moved ;-)). My only issue is there are a *lot* of Setup methods and the general consensus on StackOverflow is each Setup() should be matched by an equivalent Verify(). Seems overkill and would make the code more difficult to maintain - do I really need to do this or could I get away with Verifiable() instead?

Comment: VerifyAll() seems to be better than pairing every Setup() with Verify(). Obviously, this should be done on a case-to-case basis. You would be the best judge for this :-)

Comment: I have done what was said abve that is something like this: this.dataRecord.Setup(d => d.GetValue("WorkItemId")).Returns(1); but I got object refference is not set to instance of an object....what I did wrong? It seems that I have the same as in the comment.

Comment: Ok sorry I know what I have done wrong. I had the declaration of the new Mock<IDataRecord> in the setuptests method. And this method did not have the annotation TestInitialize. So the object never been created...